# Xamarin.Forms: bind to a code behind property in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms I would like to bind a code behind property to a label in XAML.

I found many answers and web pages about this topic, but they all cover more complex scenarios.

This is my XAML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrackValigie"
             x:Class="TrackValigie.SelViaggioPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding ?????????}" />
            </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is code behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SelViaggioPage : ContentPage
{

    private string _lblText;
    public string LblText
    {
        get
        {
            return _lblText;
        }
        set
        {
            _lblText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SelViaggioPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {

        this.LblText = "Ciao!!";

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

I would like to bind the "LblText" property to the label, **using XAML only**, that means without setting binding or binding context in code behind.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

your page will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but the binding syntax should just be

```
<ContentPage x:Name="MyPage" ... />

... 

<Label BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyPage}" Text="{Binding LblText}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, it worked! I didn't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` because `ContentPage` inherits from `BindableObject`, that already implements it.

Comment: BindingContext="{x:Reference MyPage}" alternatively

Comment: NOTE: This answer is convenient if `Label` does NOT need to bind any attributes to a VM. If you might add future binding attributes to the same label, but those new attributes need to bind to a VM (not to code behind), then see [goroth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67096989/199364), which binds ONLY the Text attribute to code-behind.

Answer (score 9):

Or if you don't want to swap the binding context for the entire control then use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Name="this"
             x:Class="SomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding SomeProp, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
            </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I think, this is the most valuable answer. In a modern MVVM pattern based application, you will almost never bind to the control's code behind and you don't want to swap the real datacontext (ViewModel). I was looking for the WPF equivalent of {Binding ElementName=this, Path=BlaBla} and this is it. This also works in a Xamarin ContentView.

Comment: See also [the earlier accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170738/199364). The accepted answer is convenient if `Label` needs *multiple* bindings to code-behind members, and does NOT require any bindings to values in a VM. THIS answer is best if `Label` might also bind other attributes to values in a VM.

Comment: XamlParseException: Can not find the object referenced by this

Comment: @trampster - then you are missing `x:Name="this"` earlier in the xaml.

Answer (score 6):

### Just add `BindingContext = this;` in code behind file.

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrackValigie"
             x:Class="TrackValigie.SelViaggioPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding LblText}" />
            </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code Behind**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SelViaggioPage : ContentPage
{

    private string _lblText;
    public string LblText
    {
        get
        {
            return _lblText;
        }
        set
        {
            _lblText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SelViaggioPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        this.LblText = "Ciao!!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the x:Name for ContentPage as mentioned by Jason's Answer .

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrackValigie"
             x:Class="TrackValigie.SelViaggioPage"
             x:Name = "MyControl"/>
```

Instead of using BindingContext, you can use ElementName

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=TestControl,Path=StudentName}"/>
```

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms XAML syntax is:
```<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={Reference TestControl}, Path=StudentName}"/>```