# Assign the value of a variable from xaml to a label

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, label

I created a shell project, and in the app.xaml I created a control template with a label inside which I have to assign the value of a variable as text, but I can't do it from the cs, any suggestions?

The label to which I have to assign the value is set like this

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderFooterTemplate">
        <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="#373B53" Spacing="0">
            
                    <Label x:Name="utente" Padding="10, 0, 0, 0" Text="Utente" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: you can't access element in a template by name.  You need to use data binding instead

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it, please?

Comment: You could create a Viewmodel-class and do the binding in the XAML: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) or set the Binding Context of the Label in code behind. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170720/xamarin-forms-bind-to-a-code-behind-property-in-xaml)